# "Fish and meat gives..." or "Fish and meat give..."?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, coordinating-conjunctions, compound-subjects

Fish and meat *gives* us protein.

Or

Fish and meat *give* us protein.

Thank you I appreciate your help.

Comment: *Fish and meat* isn't normally taken as a monolithic unit (this sentence notwithstanding), so pick plural agreement in your sentence.

Answer (score 3):

Fish and meat *give* us protein. [plural]

Jack and Jill *go* up the hill. [plural]

Jack and Jill *is* a nice story. [singular]

Fish and meat *is* sometimes called "surf and turf". [singular]

---

Conclusion: use plural with X and Y unless "X and Y" is a singular entity.

Note the last example considers the (ungodly) *combination* of fish & meat.

Comment: Another classic example is "Bacon and eggs **is** my favourite breakfast".

Comment: Very nice answer. +1.